# How to get json array from Retrofit

Tags: java, android

Here is the code of Retrofit request

```
 public void getTransactions() {
    if (common.isNetworkAvailable(WalletActivity.this)) {
        TransactionDetails transactionDetails = new TransactionDetails("employee_wise_date",
            bid, gid, "2019-01-01", "2022-07-01");

        APIService service = apiclient.getTransactions().create(APIService.class);
        Call < Object > call1 = service.
        getTransactions("vqVZ1rEKGs1yKk5ZjOZj9Yco6HEZgoy6ArD9NCwf", transactionDetails);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback < Object > () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call < Object > call,
                Response < Object > response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    common.showtoast("succes", getApplicationContext());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call < Object > call, Throwable t) {
                common.showtoast("Failed to get  transaction", getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
    } else {
        common.showtoast("Unable to connect to the internet.", WalletActivity.this);
    }
}
```

Here is the apiservice

```
 @POST("dev-wallet-spanner")
    Call<Object> getTransactions(@Header("x-api-key") String key,
                                 @Body TransactionDetails transactionDetails);
```

Here are the params which I am passing in Postman

```
{
    "op_type":"employee_wise_date", 
    "bid":"21",
    "gid":"09",
    "from_date":"2019-01-01",
    "to_date":"2022-07-01"
}
```

Here is the response which is received by Postman

```
[
    {
        "transaction_id": 10166886,
        "api_key": null,
        "arn": "null",
        "bid": "10653721",
        "created_by": "118467809",
        "created_on": "2018-06-03T13:12:46.886000000Z",
        "gid": "11",
        "ip": "2",
        "reference_id": "model",
        "remarks": "On Time Check-In",
        "status": 1,
        "transaction_amount": 100,
        "transaction_type": "credit",
        "currency": "INR",
        "platform": "co",
        "category": "f",
        "transaction_date": "2018-04-01T01:01:01.683000000Z"
    }
]
```

I am using Retrofit to make api request in my Android application. I am passing parameters with Retrofit but I am not getting response. But the same parameters working well with Postman. In Postman I am getting exact response when I try that with code I am not getting response.

I am passing the same values which I passed in Postman but the response is not coming properly. I am setting values in the modal class then I am passing that modal class in Retrofit. But response is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
 add @FormUrlEncoded you can use JsonElement in place of Object
 Call<JsonElement>.......

 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("dev-wallet-spanner")
 Call<JsonElement> getTransactions(@Header("x-api-key") String key,
                             @Body TransactionDetails transactionDetails);
```

// and in Java file same change must be done Replace Object with JsonElement

```
    if (common.isNetworkAvailable(WalletActivity.this)) {
    TransactionDetails transactionDetails = new TransactionDetails("employee_wise_date",
        bid, gid, "2019-01-01", "2022-07-01");

    APIService service = apiclient.getTransactions().create(APIService.class);
    Call < JsonElement > call1 = service.
    getTransactions("vqVZ1rEKGs1yKk5ZjOZj9Yco6HEZgoy6ArD9NCwf", transactionDetails);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback < JsonElement > () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call < JsonElement > call,
            Response < JsonElement > response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                common.showtoast("succes", getApplicationContext());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call < JsonElement > call, Throwable t) {
            common.showtoast("Failed to get  transaction", getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
} else {
    common.showtoast("Unable to connect to the internet.", WalletActivity.this);
}
 }
```

Comment: i have fixed the issue by using arraylist of modal class.thank you for your response

Answer (score -1):

in my case, i use `ResponseBody` not `Object`

So. try this.

1st, in API service,

```
@FormUrlEncoded  //add this
@POST("dev-wallet-spanner") 
Call<ResponseBody> getTransactions(@Header("x-api-key") String key, @Body TransactionDetails transactionDetails);
```

2nd, change in java code.

```
call1.enqueue(new Callback < ResponseBody> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call < ResponseBody> call,
                Response < ResponseBody> response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                           common.showtoast("succes", getApplicationContext());                       

                           //get data using try and catch
                           JSONArray jsonDataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                           //jsonDataArray is what List from retrofit
            ...
```

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but still i am not getting response

Comment: when you use retrofit, you can check params (or headers) in logcat. is this same as postman?

Comment: ok. then check post url and I edit my answer. add `@FormUrlEncoded` in your api service